# how to sum with case with oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I m having data in columns as:

| item_id | month_in | amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1500 |
| 1 | 1 | 1000 |
| 2 | 1 | 2500 |
| 3 | 1 | 2600 |
| 3 | 1 | 1000 |
| 4 | 1 | 2700 |
| 4 | 1 | 1000 |
| 1 | 2 | 1500 |
| 1 | 2 | 2000 |
| 2 | 2 | 1000 |
| 3 | 3 | 2500 |
| 3 | 3 | 2500 |
| 4 | 3 | 1000 |
| 4 | 3 | 2500 |

I want to have like this result

| item_id | januari | februari | maret |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2500 | 3500 | 0 |
| 2 | 2500 | 1000 | 0 |
| 3 | 3600 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 3700 | 0 | 3500 |

in oracle sql query how to solve this.
please help me

I have try this

```sql
select 
  item_id,
  (case  month_in=1  then sum(amout) end) AS januari
from table
group by item_id, month_in
order by item_id asc
```

but not working as I expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try a pivot query here:

```sql
SELECT
    item_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month_in = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS januari,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month_in = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS februari,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month_in = 3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS maret
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY
    item_id
ORDER BY
   item_id;
```

Comment: Please note that this assumes that there're only `month_in` 1, 2 and 3 in the table.

Comment: Thanks, it works correctly and solves my problem.

Comment: Why do you need the extra rowsets? maybe I'm missing something, but the `SELECT` already defines the columns, and the group sum will yield `0` for the missing values.

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it. This is the simplest solution, without extra hassle:

```
SELECT
    item_id,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month_in = 1 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS januari,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month_in = 2 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS februari,
    SUM(CASE WHEN month_in = 3 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS maret
from table
group by item_id
order by item_id asc
```

You don't need to define the months as a separate rowset, because the months are defined as values `1`, `2`, `3`, ... as columns. Similarly, the items are defined by the group by function.